# SQL Server FTS get tokens from string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

What is the query to get the tokens in a string from SQL Server 2008 R2?

I need it to highlight results of FREETEXT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DMV `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document` to list the words for a given document, eg something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT display_term
FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document( DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('dbo.Users') ) X
```

I had a play with [this product](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/hit-highlightingsummarization-product-for-sql-server-full-text-search/) a few years ago that does hit-highlighting, it was quite nice but I didn't go past the 30-day trial.